# Unable to access property of custom LiveData using Data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm trying to use live data with data binding for `TextInputLayout` using a class like this:

```
class MutableLiveDataWithErrorText<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    val errorText = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "" }
}
```

Now, when trying to use it for error text in the xml,

```xml
<layout>
    <data>
        <!-- ... -->
        <variable
            name="target"
            type="com.my.app.MutableLiveDataWithErrorText&lt;String&gt;" />

    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorText="@{target.errorText}">

        <!-- ... -->

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot find getter 'getErrorText' for type String.
```

I tried creating a BindingAdapter to get around this:

```
@BindingAdapter("errorTextLive")
fun setErrorTextLive(
    view: TextInputLayout,
    liveDataWithErrorText: MutableLiveDataWithErrorText<String>
) {
    if (liveDataWithErrorText.errorText.value.isNullOrEmpty().not()) {
        view.error = liveDataWithErrorText.errorText.value
    }
}
```

with xml assignment changed to:

```xml
app:errorTextLive="@{target}"
```

which makes the compilation succeed, but changes to `target.errorText` are no longer observed, instead it observes changes in `target`, updating `errorText` only when `target`'s value changes.

Is there a way to make the it observe `target.errorText`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make the it observe target.errorText?

I don't think so. The problem is, that the databinding library is resolving `target` inside `target.errorText` first and sees that it is of type `MutableLiveData<String>`, it then automatically gets the value of `target`, which is of type String and then tries to call getErrorText() on that String object, which leads to the error you see.

I had a similar use-case and I resorted to creating the following class:

```
class <T> ValidatableValue {

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<T>() // The actual value.

    // Other helper livedatas and functions.
    val isValid = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun validate() { ... }
}
```

I can then use all these LiveData objects in the databinding layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's *bad pattern* to pass view model as *set of fields* instead of one composite object.
If you need to pass at least two variable to data-binding, you need to create view model with this fields - it help you to make changes more flexible.

For example, you can define view model like this one:

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    /**
     * Expose MutableLiveData to enable two way data binding
     */
    val textData = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "" }
    /**
     * Expose LiveData for read only fields
     */
    val errorText = Transformations.map(textData, ::validateInput)

    /**
     * Validate input on the fly
     */
    private fun validateInput(input: String): String? = when {
        input.isBlank() -> "Input is blank!"
        else -> null
    }
}
```

on layout side it very closer to your variant:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.SimpleViewModel" />

    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorText="@{vm.errorText}">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:text="@={vm.textData}"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

*NOTE: it is not necessary `SimpleViewModel` to extend `ViewModel`, but it allow your data to survive configuration changes out of the box*